# Java ArrayList with custom add function

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

I know it is possible to override the .add behaviour of ArrayList, but how can it be? Where is it defined in the Java docs? What does it mean to have curly braces {} after the generic definition ?

```
List<Element> SortedListOfElements = new ArrayList<Element>() {
    public boolean add(Element mt) {
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(this, mt);
        if (index < 0) {
            index = ~index;
        }
        super.add(index, mt);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem overriding ArrayList add method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196149/problem-overriding-arraylist-add-method)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: "I know it is possible to change the .add behaviour of ArrayList" => Well, without any bytecode manipulation this is _not_ possible!

Comment: Your code segment does not show a _changing_ of the add method, it shows the _overriding_ of it in a subclass. This is one of the core concepts of OOP.

Comment: Is the Segment/Element mismatch a typo?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, of course, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

> *Where is it defined in the Java docs? What does it mean to have curly braces {} after the generic definition?*

This is called anonymous class, you may need to check [this tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), such classes do not have specific names in the code, they are used to instantiate interfaces/abstract classes, or modify some known methods as in your case with `List::add`.  The curly braces after the constructor are meant to define a class with some overridden/implemented methods.

Declaration of anonymous classes is described in [JLS 15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5).

---

Your solution seems to be almost fine with a few comments:

- if `Collections::binarySearch` is applied to instances of `Segment` class, this class has to implement `Comparable<Segment>` interface
- method `List::addAll(Collection<? extends T> collection)` should be overridden too, because default implementation just appends the elements of `collection`.
- similarly, a constructor accepting a collection, may need to be overridden.

Thus it would be worth to provide a generic implementation of a "sorted" list instead of the anonymous class:

```java
public class SortedArrayList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public SortedArrayList() {}

    public SortedArrayList(Collection<? extends T> collection) {
        super(collection);
        this.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T item) {
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(this, item);
        if (index < 0) {
            index = ~index;
        }
        super.add(index, item);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> collection) {
        for (T item : collection) {
            this.add(item);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
List<Element> sortedList = new SortedArrayList<>();
```

Comment: My question is where in the javadocs it says I can put a custom function in a curly braces after the new ArrayList<Element>()? What part of the Java syntax is that?

Comment: This is called anonymous class, you may need to check [this tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), such classes do not have specific names in the code, they are used to instantiate interfaces/abstract classes, or modify some known methods as in your case with `List::add`.  Declaration of anonymous classes is described in [JLS 15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)

Comment: Thanks. Better to use @Override before the function, this what made me confuse.