# How does method over riding work in case where method signature remains same but generic parameters differ?

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I was trying following example:

```
class BaseClass {
    public void methodA(Class<?> cl) {
        System.out.println("Base.methodA()");
    }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    public void methodA(Class cl) {
        System.out.println("Sub.methodA()");
    }
}

public class OverrideEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
        BaseClass s = new SubClass();

        b.methodA(Class.class);
        s.methodA(Class.class);
    }
}
```

Output: 
Base.methodA()
Sub.methodA()

But if I change over riding method argument other way around as follows:

```
class BaseClass {
    public void methodA(Class cl) {
        System.out.println("Base.methodA()");
    }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    public void methodA(Class<?> cl) {
        System.out.println("Sub.methodA()");
    }
}

public class OverrideEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
        BaseClass s = new SubClass();

        b.methodA(Class.class);
        s.methodA(Class.class);
    }
}
```

I get compilation error. It says "Name clash: The method methodA(Class) of type SubClass has the same erasure as methodA(Class) of type BaseClass but does not override it".

Why is that?

Comment: This answer explains the issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/502770/1030409

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type erasure, overriding and generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502614/type-erasure-overriding-and-generics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameterized type `Class<?>` is a subtype of the raw type `Class` (§[4.10.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.2)).

Thus for any `x` the call `s.methodA(x)` in the first example would also be valid if rewritten:

```
((BaseClass)s).methodA(x)
```

This is not true for the second example.

Imagine `x` being of type `Class` which is not a subtype of `Class<?>`. That call
would be illegal because the argument's type is not a subtype of the formal parameter's type.

This means that `methodA` of `SubClass` does not override `methodA` of `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#227927), you can override a method if (amongst other things): *The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.*

That means that ( [JLS again](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#38649) ):
*- m2 has the same signature as m1, or

- the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure of the signature of m2.*

In your attempt to override `methodA`, you have the same type erasure but you don't have the same signature. In this very chapter of the jls, there's a discussion on the matter you are describing.