# need for casting to a generic type in java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

while implementing a priority queue using a linkedlist(actually an inner class `Node`),I coded the `insert()` and `max()` methods as below.It uses the lazy approach of keeping the items unordered and then seaching through them for the maximum element only when a `max()` or `deleteMax()` call occurs.

```
public class LinkedListMaxPQ<Item extends Comparable<Item>>{
    private int N;
    private Node head;

   public void insert(Item item) {
       Node old = head;
       head = new Node();
       head.item = item;
       head.next = old;
       N++;
    }

    public Item max() {
        Item maxitem = (Item) this.head.item;
        for(Node t=head.next;t!=null;t=t.next){
            if(gt(t.item,maxitem)){
            maxitem = (Item) t.item;
            }
        }
        return maxitem;
    }
    private boolean gt(Comparable x,Comparable y){
    return x.compareTo(y) > 0;
}



   private class Node<Item extends Comparable<Item>>{
      Item item;
      Node next;
   }

}
```

I am wondering why I need the cast in `Item maxitem = (Item) this.head.item` ? Since the class uses a generic type `Item which extends Comparable` and the inner class also uses Item extends Comparable ,one would think that such a cast is unnecessary.

If I omit the cast

```
Item maxitem = this.head.item;
```

compiler will complain that there is a type mismatch

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparable to Item

Can someone explain why this occurs?

Comment: because isn't a Item is something that you can compare with Item, isn't the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type erasure, overriding and generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502614/type-erasure-overriding-and-generics)  Using `for(Node<Item> t=head.next;t!=null;t=t.next){` will remove the type mismatch error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Java is treating `Item` as a type parameter in the `Node` class declaration (which has no relation to the `Item` type parameter declared in `LinkedListMaxPQ<Item extends Comparable<Item>>`).

This declaration -

```
private class Node<Item extends Comparable<Item>>{
    Item item;
    Node next;
}
```

tells the compiler that you are creating a private class which has a type parameter called `Item`, and which is a subtype of `Comparable<Item>`. During type erasure, this `Item` will be replaced by its bound, which is of type `Comparable`. That's why you need that explicit cast.

Also, the following line -

```
private Node head;
```

creates a raw type `Node`, without any type information available to it. You should get a warning for this line.

To remedy this, declare your `head` as follows -

```
private Node<Item> head;
```

and create an instance in the following way -

```
head = new Node<Item>();  // if you are using jdk 6 or lesser
head = new Node<>();  // if you are using jdk 7
```

Update all the `Node` references in a similar way, and your warnings should be gone.

If you need further clarification on type parameter bound, you can read [one of my blog posts](https://sayemdb.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/an-introduction-to-generics-in-java-part-5/) where I've tried to explain how type parameter bound works.

Comment: The problem is not the `head` variable but `t` in the loop.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: It's in all of the node declaration. I have just provided the above declaration as a sample, but if you still insist, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I don't insist, the error is because of how `t` is declared, not how  `head` is. Changing `head` only wouldn't solve the error and answer the question.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: Well, I already mentioned about the raw types and the problem that it creates previously. Anyway, I hope it's OK now.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
private class Node{
...
```

by having it as:

```
private class Node<Item extends Comparable<Item>>{
```

you are making a **new** generic type called `Item` that is **not** the same as the `Item` type of the enclosing class even though it has the same name.

Answer (score 0):

its simple, as you didnt specified type when you create head, node.head has type object

this should fix your problem

```
public class LinkedListMaxPQ<Item extends Comparable<Item>>{
    private int N;
    private Node<Item> head;

   public void insert(Item item) {
       Node<Item> old = head;
       head = new Node<Item>();
       head.item = item;
       head.next = old;
       N++;
    }

    public Item max() {
        Item maxitem =  this.head.item;
        for(Node<Item> t=head.next;t!=null;t=t.next){
            if(gt(t.item,maxitem)){
            maxitem =  t.item;
            }
        }
        return maxitem;
    }



   private class Node<Item extends Comparable<Item>>{
      Item item;
      Node<Item> next;
   }

}
```

Comment: The problem is not the `head` variable but `t` in the loop.

Comment: i have to disagree with you, specifing type, is solving described problem

Comment: It ain't getting rid of the error to declare `head` only, you need to change `t` to remove the `Type mismatch` error. Unless Eclipse got it all wrong...

Comment: for this code which i just uploaded, obly error which eclipse is showing me is missing method `gt`

Answer (score 0):

As @JonathanDrapeau pointed out, the answer is simply: change the declaration of `t` variable to `Node<Item>`:

```
    for (Node<Item> t = head.next; t != null; t = t.next){
        if (gt(t.item, maxitem)){
        maxitem = t.item;
        }
    }
```

**The second option**: remove the type argument form `Node` class definition, if you want to refer to the same type as in the parent `LinkedListMaxPQ` class:

```
public class LinkedListMaxPQ<Item extends Comparable<Item>> {

    ...

    private class Node {
        Item item;
        Node next;
    }
}
```