# How does synchronized generic method behave?

Tags: java

I have a question about the behavior of the following type of code

> public synchronized < T > List< T > executeSelect(Class< T > c) { }

If I execute the code queryEngine.executeSelect(A.class); in one thread and queryEngine.executeSelect(B.class); in another thread do those threads treat the method as one (and one waits for another) or two different and they are executed concurrently?

I want to have a DB query engine that is behind a web service and returns object of a given type from a database. I also want to use just one connection to the database and open / close it for query execution.

Comment: try this: set a break point in execute select.  this will tell you if there are two executeSelect() methods (like in C) or only one executeSelect() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `synchronized` modifier leads to the methods being executed after acquiring an implicit monitor which is released after the method returns. This monitor is:

- The **instance** the method is executed on for a non-`static` method
- The **class** the method is defined for for a `static` method

You can therefore translate your non-static method

```
public synchronized <T> List<T> executeSelect(Class<T> c) { 
  // code
}
```

to

```
public <T> List<T> executeSelect(Class<T> c) { 
  synchronized(this) {
    // code
  }
}
```

As a matter of fact, the JRockit VM even applied this translation internally and I suspect the HotSpot VM to do the same.

Thus, it does not matter if the method is run with a specific generic argument (especially since the runtime is not aware of generic types which are erased after compilation) or even which non-static method is executed on an instance as any method acquires the very same monitor. It is only the instance on which a method is called that determines which monitor the `synchronized` modifier implicitly refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Generic method does not result in multiple implementations. Due to type erasure it is equivivalent to a single `synchronized List executeSelect(Class)` method and this method is used by both threads regardless of specific parameter types.

So usual rules of calling `synchronized` method on the same instance apply - multiple threads will not be able to execute it concurrently.

You can read more about type erasure in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502614/type-erasure-overriding-and-generics) question and follow links provided in them.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are only for compile time so runtime it behaves like just another `syncronized` method.

```
public synchronized < T > List< T > executeSelect(Class< T > c) { }
```

will be compiled to

```
public synchronized List executeSelect(Class c) { }
```

It is just that compile time if you call the method like below that compiler will know that you are passing incorrect type as argument.

```
List<String> = obj.<String>executeSelect(new Integer(1));
```