# java error both methods have same erasure for generics

Tags: java, generics, compilation

I have an interface with these two methods.

```
E2EResult sendRoutingRequests(List<RoutingRequest> routingRequestsList);

E2EResult sendRoutingRequests(List<String> routingRequestsList);
```

The compiler shouts for:

`java error both methods have same erasure`

I saw some posts talking about `same erasure` for java generics.

Can someone explain why is that?

It's different q than this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586506/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type-part-2), because I don't deal with wild card.

Comment: FYI: It is not different than that other post.

Comment: It's not different than the post you linked. It's the same issue (same signature after type erasure) dispite the wildcards.

Comment: That's not the question, but what is the semantic behind both methods? If the `List<String>` is kind of _raw_ routing requests, you can name the method explicitly, e.g. `sendRawRoutingRequests(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler removes the generic type parameters, so `List<String>` and `List<RoutingRequest>` become List, and thus both methods have the same signature.

Comment: but doesn't it compile to different class files?  `List<RoutingRequest>` and `List<String>`

Comment: @Elad Benda No it doesn't. You can easily find out: `List<String> l = ...; List<RoutingRequest> l2 = ...; System.out.println(l.getClass().equals(l2.getClass()));`

Comment: Generics types are removed before compiling so the compiler doesn't see generic types. It only sees List.

Comment: @EladBenda It is compiled as `List<Object>`, and RoutingRequest and String are instanceof Object.