# Generic method inheritance

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

The question is about the following block of code:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static class A {
        public void f(int x) {
            System.out.println("1");
        }

        public void f(Object x) {
            System.out.println("2");
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public <T> void f(T x) {   // *
            System.out.println("3");
        }
    }
}
```

Line `*` does not compile, with the following error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Name clash: The method f(T) of type SomeClass.B has the same erasure as f(Object) of type SomeClass.A but does not override it

**To avoid duplicate**:
I've looked at: [Type erasure, overriding and generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502614/type-erasure-overriding-and-generics?rq=1) , [Method has the same erasure as another method in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type) and while I've received an answer (well partially, because I still didn't completely understand it) why there is a compilation error (to avoid ambiguity because of type erasure? is this it?) the main problem is that I don't understand why, if I switch between the two methods `f(Object x)` and `f(T x)` so the code will be like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static class A {
        public void f(int x) {
            System.out.println("1");
        }


        public <T> void f(T x) {
            System.out.println("3");
        }

    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public void f(Object x) {
            System.out.println("2");
        }
    }
}
```

I do not receive a compilation error.
Why is this happening? What is the key difference for which for the first code I get a compilation error and for the second I don't. Would love some explaining on this, thanks!

Comment: This is essentially by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/502770/129570): "*For overriding with instance methods you need the overriding method to be a subsignature of the overridden method (JLS 8.4.8.1)*".  `void f(Object x)` is a subsignature of `<T> void f(T x)`, but not vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method has the same erasure as another method in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One of the answers to one of the questions you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/502770/129570) essentially already addresses this:

> For overriding with instance methods you need the overriding method to be a subsignature of the overridden method.

To dig into this a bit more, [JLS 8.4.8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) says this:

> An instance method m<sub>C</sub> declared in or inherited by class C, overrides from C another method m<sub>A</sub> declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:
>
> - [...]
> - The signature of m<sub>C</sub> is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m<sub>A</sub>.

A subsignature is defined in [JLS 8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> The signature of a method m<sub>1</sub> is a subsignature of the signature of a method m<sub>2</sub> if either:
>
> - [...]
> - the signature of m<sub>1</sub> is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m<sub>2</sub>.

You're considering the following two signatures:

1. `void f(Object x)`
2. `<T> void f(T x)`

The erasure of #2 is `void f(Object x)`, thus #1 is a subsignature of it.  However, *vice versa* is not true.

Comment: Thanks, I've probably missed it as answering my "second" question under all the text

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is *type erasure* as written in the error. This means that your generic type constraint/definition `<T>` in class `B` is only regarded by the compiler to do type checking. However, that you put the `<T>` there is not available in the runtime byte code to do the method resolution.

As such have a look at your `public void <T> f(T x)` when the type is erased - all that remains is `Object` (it's just something you can stuff as first parameter). But then this is the same signature as in class `A` - yielding you the error.

In the second case it's perfectly fine since your class `B` method will accept any object - so it will of course accept any `<T>` which you specified in the signature of `A`.